# Open ALOS PALSAR DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem

Does anybody know how to open an ALOS PALSAR DEM in QGIS?

There are two TIFF files included, but, their volume is very low and also the quality.

I think there is another way of opening it.

Since ALOS PALSAR is the single source of freely-available worldwide DEM with resolution of 12.5, it is very important to be able to open it in QGIS.

The data can be downloaded from: https://search.asf.alaska.edu/#/

Comment: Please add a link to the data source, then it is easier to help.

Comment: gdalinfo reports about the files that you have would help too.

Comment: I want a way to do this inside QGIS, like in Processing toolbox.

Comment: Specifics please on exactly what format your data is in, how you tried to import it into QGIS, and where you're stuck. It would really help to give a WeTransfer or DropBox link to exactly the data you want to work with.